# Message passing between python running natively and python running via wine

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing, wine

I'm on a linux machine that needs to use windows drivers to talk to a piece of hardware. I'm using ctypes.windll to interact with with the driver in a python process run via wine. I'd like to be able to pass messages to this wine-python process from another python process just running natively. Any ideas where I might start?

Comment: hm. *Any* message passing library, maybe? Like Sockets, zeroMQ, FIFO file IO, ICE,...

Comment: The answer provided there has the wine-based process establish a networked server that receives commands and sends output to a native client

Comment: Mike, Awesome! I think you might just want to close this question yourself, write your application, and maybe even come back and self-answer your question later on, if you find out something new (self-answering questions is explicitely encouraged around here)!